# Rails 3 Secure Cookie and HTTP only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

In my rails app, I am using a cookie called `user_session` user can access my rails app using https or http they can configure it.

**Problem**
 user_session cookie is set to http only but I want to make it as secure too.

If user access my app using **http** then the cookie will be in **http only** if he is using **https** then it will be set as secure cookie. I don't want to use 2 different cookies.

Configuration:

```
SampleApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_user_session'
```

If I force `:secure => true` then this cookie is not available for the users who are all accessing in http request.

If any other details required please comment it out.

Comment: Why are you still offering HTTP access? If security is an issue you care about, then forcing HTTPS should be one of your very first measures.

Comment: @CBroe just want give flexibility to users. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would users need “flexibility” in that regard? Take Facebook for example, they moved all users to HTTPS a while ago - if they don’t need that kind of “flexibility”, then why do you …?